# Why is there an attribute error appearing just after pip install of Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

After fresh installing Python 3.7 and all the modules required (ie numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc), I successfully install seaborn, but when I try to import it into a file it raises an attribute error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\TestFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 345, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 171, in <module>
    from . import distributions
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _continuous_distns
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py", line 113, in <module>
    class norm_gen(rv_continuous):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py", line 175, in norm_gen
    `optimizer` argument is ignored.\n\n""")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\doccer.py", line 159, in _doc
    start_of_notes = cls_docstring.find(notes_header)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

It doesn't show up in pip list either.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32>python -m pip install seaborn --force-reinstall
Installing collected packages: numpy, pyparsing, six, cycler, setuptools, kiwisolver, python-dateutil, matplotlib, scipy, pytz, pandas, seaborn
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.0.1 matplotlib-3.0.0 numpy-1.15.1 pandas-0.23.4 pyparsing-2.2.1 python-dateutil-2.7.3 pytz-2018.5 scipy-1.1.0 seaborn-0.9.0 setuptools-40.4.1 six-1.11.0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
cycler          0.10.0
kiwisolver      1.0.1
llvmlite        0.24.0
matplotlib      2.2.2
numba           0.39.0
numpy           1.14.5
pandas          0.23.4
pip             18.0
pyparsing       2.2.0
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pytz            2018.5
scipy           1.1.0
setuptools      39.0.1
six             1.11.0
```

Comment: Those 2 outputs of `python -m pip install...` and `pip list` look conflicting (different versions of libraries, e.g. numpy and complete misses like seaborn). Are you sure, that both are using the binaries of the same distribution? It looks, like you got a second py-install and one of those calls is using a system-path to use a different binary (e.g. when pip is not in `Python37-32` but `Python37-32\bin`, but that's random guessing).

Comment: When i use the code `python -m pip list` I obtain 
`Package         Version
--------------- -------
cycler          0.10.0
Cython          0.28.5
kiwisolver      1.0.1
llvmlite        0.24.0
matplotlib      3.0.0
numba           0.39.0
numpy           1.15.1
pandas          0.23.4
patsy           0.5.0
pip             18.0
pyparsing       2.2.1
python-dateutil 2.7.3
pytz            2018.5
scipy           1.1.0
seaborn         0.9.0
setuptools      40.4.1
six             1.11.0
statsmodels     0.9.0
wheel           0.31.1` So I don't think I am using a different binary.

Comment: Also I am able to use all my other packages and they have the corresponding correct versions listed. Is it a bug within seaborn?